# Long term storage of parts

Tags: maintenance, subaru, parts, restoration

I recently bought some spare parts for my Subaru Forester XT and would like to store them the right way until I need them. Specifically, I have a turbo, injectors, exhaust and intercooler that needs to go in the garage. How would you guys handle this? I was thinking WD40, mutton cloth and black bags.

I expect them to lie around unused for around 1 to 3 years.

Comment: Please vote on [this tag synonym](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/o2-sensor/synonyms) if you haven't already. I'll delete this comment when you let me know one way or the other if you have. :D Thanks.

Comment: I just did. ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in a high humidity area, I would:

- Coat the part in WD-40 (at least pieces which are made of or have exposed metal pieces).
- Put them into a [large Zip Lock Style Vacuum Storage bag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SDRDYFK) along with ~six [oxygen absorbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028AG8RO)
- Vacuum out the storage bag
- Place bag on the shelf and *leave it alone*.

You may want to put something around the part so any sharp edges aren't coming in contact with the plastic of the bag. The reason for WD-40 is not because of it's superior rust preventive qualities, because there are plenty of other products out there. The reason to use WD-40 is because of its *water displacement* qualities (thus the **WD** in the name).

This method should keep your parts fresh for a *long time* if left undisturbed with seals intact and bag uncompromised.

Comment: I'll just go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Comment: Great answer. I live in a high humidity area (and sometimes have my vehicle on an island) and I have noticed over a few years that on a Subaru engine the same parts listed by the OP but on the vehicle have corrosion on them. Same effects on an alloy engine in a sportsbike as well.